# JSLint Expected 'new' and instead saw '.'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am facing this message from JSLint

```
Expected 'new' and instead saw '.'.
```

The line of code that is responsible:

```
utc = Date.UTC(year, month, date);
```

This function returns a string.

So JSLint is expecting new instead of the "." between `Date` and `UTC()`. JSLint expects new in front of constructors and it also assumes that functions starting with Capital letter is constructor by convention.

I do not have control over this as this is a pre-build function. It doesn't take a form to be constructed with `new`.

Also I tried to ignore it by following options suggested in other answers:

```
/*jslint ignore:start */
/*ignore:true */
/*ignore jslint start*/
// jslint ignore:line
/*jsl:ignore*/
```

None of these worked !

I am looking forward for a workaround "new" or ignore that particular line or section of code. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Hm, have you tried not using jslint at all?

Comment: Code is fine. I just want the jslint to ignore this particular line or write the code in certain manner jslint will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [filed a bug for this behavior](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/issues/178) and [Crockford fixed it the same day](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/f8b64f96137abe54c70bc6518bb709191289c044). (He's an incredibly responsive maintainer.) Use the most recent version of JSLint to fix this behavior. It is not yet on jslint.com, but I expect it will be soon.

This is a very unusual case, since capital letters normally indicate constructors. Using an initial capital `U` in `UTC` for a non-constructor function is contrary to JSLint's recommended style, but in this case there's nothing to be done about it, as its been part of the standard for at least five years. JSLint simply needed a narrow exception to its "initial capital means constructor" rule to allow the specific standards-required `UTC` non-constructor function.

Comment: This issue is popping up again in after the latest commit dated "2016-05-05" new..().